# Autocannon vs Jmeter in load testing via Cloudflare

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, cloudflare, ddos

We're trying to benchmark our application. We've tried tools, autocannon and jmeter. 
I've noticed that when we use autocannon, we couldn't get any response from Cloudflare unless we turn off the orange cloud. But when we use jmeter we get responses regardless.

I would like to understand why this is happening.

I know that by default Cloudflare has unmetered ddos protection turned on. Is it possible that requests from jmeter are not considered as ddos attack? Or am I missing a setup in my autocannon configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Well-behaved JMeter load test generates the same network footprint as the real browser does](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).
2. Looking into [Autocannon](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon) it doesn't seem to be supporting at least:

   - handling embedded resources like browsers do
   - implementation [HTTP Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
   - working with [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))
   - [think times](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9)
   - etc.

Assuming all above Cloudflare might consider traffic generated by Autocannon fraudulent. So I would recommend:

- Sticking to JMeter as it is more advanced tool even out of the box and it can be extended by [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) (thanks to modular JMeter architecture)
- Temporary disabling all 3rd-party services (Cloudflare, any captchas, external authentication systems, payment gateways, etc.) as your test needs to focus solely on your application, not the integrations.